# What kind of graph is this? A pie chart?

Tags: percentages

Besides a gross use of Comic Sans, what kind of graph is this? I've seen it used for population statistics before, but I don't know what it's called.

[image]

My first instinct was to just say "bullet chart" due to process of elimination. After researching what a bullet chart is, which includes thresholds and targets, I'm now leaning toward some kind of unorthodox pie chart since it's dealing solely of percentage makeup of the whole.

I'm still not convinced that this is simply called a "pie chart," but it's all I got.

Comment: what's the Q in the pic - 'what t is the following' - what's the 't'

Comment: I think you are right and your reasoning is good.  But I don't like calling it a pie chart either.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Probably a typo if I had to guess judging by font-choice. This is the entire scope of the problem.

Comment: its a scatterplot - the Q is wrong

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Doesn't a scatter plot involve points on an X and Y axis? The positions of these colored squares seem insignificant.

Comment: In terms of functionality, I can't deny that it's most like a pie chart of the given options.

Comment: yes, but it's nothing like a pie chart, which look like pies. if you took a petri dish and placed some blotting paper on it it would look like that

Comment: it also looks like unloading an Uzi into a wall, so I'm going with bullet chart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Partition Chart]

This is a **Partition Chart** which is similar in data structure to a Pie Chart.

Here's how you make it in excel -> http://peltiertech.com/ineffective-chart-partition-chart/

The squares of each colour correspond to a certain value. Aggregate these squares together and you've got a pie chart! The total number of squares is also a constant, like with Pie charts total slices together always make 360 degrees.

Comment: And you even found the source image! Well done, sir!

Answer (score 1):

**e) None of the previous ones.**

The graph is a scatter plot of filled squares, also know as fragmented partition chart.

Answer (score 0):

I've given the question "+1" beacsue it led me to look up what exactly a bullet chart is. Like the questioner, I have now done a little research and am convinced that a bullet graph needs to show progress achieved towards a particular goal.

Moving on, let us consider the other possibilities.

Bar charts and line graphs (we seem to be using chart/graph as equivalents) should have a scale showing the variable and a scale showing the frequency. This chart has neither, so it's not one of them. Although it may be close to being a very badly drawn "stacked bar chart"...?

The key feature of a pie chart is that the area devoted to a particular attribute is proportional to the frequency of that attribute. Normally they are drawn as portions of a circle, but a pie could be rectangular, in which case a rectangular pie chart might be possible (although I have never seen one before).

This chart has the property that area seems to be proportional to frequency, so I would go for pie chart. It even has the percentages which some pie charts include.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO it is a bar graph as seen from bird perspective

Comment: Maybe true. But not particularly helpful. Sorry.